# Вопрос по LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

```
rainMusic=new Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
```

Пользуюсь автокомплитом в Идее. По итогу Идея пишет что не может разрешить имя 'newMusic'. Гугл выдает старинные вопросы о подобной проблеме, но ответов в тех постах нет.
Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название плиз. Кнопка "править"

Answer (score -1):

Пиши 
Music mus;
Public class...
В методе create() пишешь mus =Gdx.audio.newmusic(Gdx.files.internal("твоя музыка.mp3"))):
mus.play();
Также это может быть по другой причине поменяй  название переменной Music на какую нибудь другую потому что это может быть занята

Comment: Отформатируйте код, пожалуйста. P.S. минус не мой

Comment: Проблема была в ключевом слове new.